# Docker failfure in Hyperledger Tutorials

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, docker-toolbox

I played Hyperledger in these days, followed the [hyperledger docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io), when I ran [the script in the network tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html) and got the following errors, [the source codes of this tutorials is here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples.git):

```
$ ./byfn.sh -m up -l node
Starting for channel 'mychannel' with CLI timeout of '10' seconds and CLI delay of '3' seconds
Continue? [Y/n] y
proceeding ...
LOCAL_VERSION=1.2.0
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=1.2.0
Creating peer1.org2.example.com ... done
Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... done
Creating orderer.example.com    ... done
Creating peer0.org2.example.com ... done
Creating peer1.org1.example.com ... done
Creating cli                    ... done
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"scripts/script.sh\": stat scripts/script.sh: no such file or directory": unknown
ERROR !!!! Test failed
```

I was using the latest Docker Toolbox 18.06.01 under Windows 10, any one here tried this with Docker Toolbox? I am not sure this is a Docker Toolbox problem or a generic Docker problem under Windows system.

Comment: That error looks like you are trying to open a file instead of running a bash command. Share the code it is attempting to execute instead of us digging through that tutorial site.

Comment: @dfundako Updated my original post. Just want to confirm if this scripts works under DockerToolbox or Docker for Windows(it seems Docker Toolbox is dying), in the docs it mentioned Docker Toolbox, but most of docs seems be done under Mac(and Docker for Mac). For me, It is incompatible that Docker for Windows(using Hyperv) will be conflict with VirtulBox which I have to use it with others tools, such as Vagrant etc.

Comment: the best environment to run fabric under is Ubuntu 16.04 or 18 with a slight script modification. Definitely not windows.

Answer (score 0):

> any one here tried this with Docker Toolbox?

me. but I can say that ms-windows as a fabric's host is far from best solution.

Your error shows after the start of the fabric's. You can modify **docker YAML** or **byfn.sh** script and comment **start.sh** execution. Then repeat **script/scripts.sh** commands manually to find the problem.